# ng-class with function call that generate random string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Materialize Library for my Angular app. The problem is i am trying to add random class name so that the background would be different for each tag.

```
<ul class="inline-list" ng-repeat="feature in features">
 <li class="chip" ng-class="getColor()">{{feature}}</li>
</ul>
```

And my controller,

```
function ProjectsController($scope) {
    $scope.features = ['React', 'Redux', 'Firebase'];
    const colorClass = ['pink lighten-3', 'indigo lighten-2', 'lime accent-1',
     'amber accent-2','grey darken-2', 'deep-orange darken-1', 'green accent-2', 
     'teal', 'purple', 'red darken-1'];
    $scope.getColor = () => {
      return colorClass[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)]
    }
}
```

The browser throw an error as:

> angular.js:10633 Error: [$rootScope:infdig]

Please give me some clue to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you get in infinite loop of $scope.digest().

[Check documentation about [$rootScope:infdig] error:](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig)

I would suggest to rewrite your controller like this:

```
function ProjectsController($scope) {

   const colorClass = ['pink lighten-3', 'indigo lighten-2', 'lime accent-1',  'amber accent-2','grey darken-2', 'deep-orange darken-1', 'green accent-2', 
 'teal', 'purple', 'red darken-1'];


  function getColor() {
     return colorClass[
             Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 )
          ]
  }

  $scope.features = [
         { technology: 'React', color: getColor() },
         { technology: 'Redux', color: getColor() },
         { technology: 'Firebase', color: getColor() },
  ];
}
```

Also, you should edit yout HTML:

```
<ul class="inline-list" ng-repeat="feature in features">
    <li class="chip" ng-class="feature.color">{{feature.technology}}</li>
</ul>
```

Hope, it helps

Comment: That complete solve my problem! Thank you man! I really appreciate your help.